# How to reset: Maven, GitFlow and GitLab

Tags: git, maven, git-flow

I have inherited a LARGE Java project and am currently making small code changes (C# programmer here). Each time I start a new Helpdesk Ticket I create a new hot fix branch using the command:

```
mvn gitflow:hotfix-start
```

then make my changes, compile, test etc. Once everything was finished I do a:

```
mvn gitflow:hotfix-finish
```

this caused two commits in gitlab - a merge AND an update of the hot fix i.e. it created these commits with the following comment:

```
  Merge branch 'hotfix/1.7.2'
  Update versions for hotfix
```

What seems to have happened is that the last hotfix did not create the second commit:

```
  Update versions for hotfix
```

Unfortunately I did not notice this and am now 2 hot fixes on an now the hotfix-finish crashes with some obscure error message. I have tried everything to get this running again - have even had friends look into it but we cannot correct the error.

The main, develop and hotfix branches are now totally out of sync and I can no longer finish any branch!

Here is my question. Is there any way that I can just make my current hotfix branch the main branch - let it be the version 1.8 for all I care? I just want to be able to create new branches again and carry on working... i.e. I am looking for something line

```
mvn gitflow:reset 1.8.0
```

I currently have a perfectly working 1.7.4 version - I want to get this to be 1.8.0 and start creating hot fixes again!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I did to fix this was:

1. create a new project in GitLab
2. copy the code to the new project
3. create the content delivery and manual deployment in Jenkins

That solved the problem for me....

Comment: did you imported the entire history as well?

Comment: nope - just archived the old project - its not nice but, as I wrote I wasted way to much time on this 